# Multi-master cross-region postgresql replication

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rds

I am new in AWS, currently m working to configure Multi-master cross-region for postgresql. In my scenario i am using postgresql database in RDS, i have two db instances in different region, for example 1st db instance in (US-East) Region and other db instance in (US-West)Region. In each region we configure db-instance as master-slave replications using(Multi-AZ deployment).

So my query is how i configure cross-region between these two db-instance which is in different regions to perform DML(Insert/Update/Delete) opertaion like if i performe insertion 1 instance (database) master then the same updated data replicate on second instance master of different region and vice-versa.?

[Please find the attachemnt for scenario diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hUFJ.jpg)

Comment: I'd be surprised if RDS supported this at the present time. If it does, you'll definitely face problems with schema changes, etc.

Comment: @CraigRinger yep DDL cannot be replicate and using MMR for PostgreSQL you will risk table locking which is cause data lost or not commited even stopper

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use bucardo for postgresql replication between 2 RDS instances (Master to slave). Use the following link to setup replication:

https://www.installvirtual.com/how-to-install-bucardo-for-postgres-replication/

I have tested this in single region but you can try to test between different regions.